# Why secondary coil in transformer have continues one direction current

Tags: transformer

In primary side of transformer it change magnet north to south as ac current flow and it keep changing as ac wave passed through  coil. I do not understand why on secondary side we got a current which flow in one direction. Why not on secondary side current change its direction as magnet change in primary side.

Comment: how are you determining that the current flows in only one direction in the secondary winding?

Comment: It doesn't. It's AC too. Perhaps you are thinking about the output of a rectifier (which often follows a transformer)?

Comment: Probably referring to a switchmode flyback power transformer, the power goes into the transformer as pulsed DC, and comes out as pulsed DC.

Answer (score 2):

The input and the output of a transformer are undoubtedly AC.

[image]

You are most probably referring to a DC power supply which is a transformer plus a rectifier and a capacitor on the secondary side.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I m talking about ac current. If current flow forward and back than how electric appliance works on it

Comment: Hi Garry, The rectifier converts AC to DC which is unidirectional.

Comment: Sorry I m not talking about DC. I want to know about ac only.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to a wall wart transformer. In that case the rectifier would be in the equipment.